# react-navigation is not working in react-native actions

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-navigation

Please check my code below i have to navigate to **EmployeeCreate** after login success .I use this in `dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'EmployeeCreate' }));` in my AuthActions.js. but not working.Previously i used 'react-native-router-flux' instead of  react-navigation. Iam new to react-native and couldn't find the issue.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
const config = {
apiKey: "###",
authDomain: "###",
databaseURL: "###",
projectId: "###",
storageBucket: "###,
messagingSenderId: "0000000"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

 render() {
   const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router />
  </Provider>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import EmployeeList from './components/EmployeeList';
import EmployeeCreate from './components/EmployeeCreate';
import EmployeeEdit from './components/EmployeeEdit';


const RouterComponent = StackNavigator({
   LoginForm : {screen : LoginForm},
 EmployeeCreate : {screen :EmployeeCreate},
   EmployeeEdit:{screen:EmployeeEdit},
 },
{
  headerMode : 'none',
  navigationOptions:{
  headerVisible : false,
}
}
)
export default RouterComponent;
```

AuthActions.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
    import {
      EMAIL_CHANGED,
      PASSWORD_CHANGED,
      LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
      LOGIN_USER
    } from './types';

    export const emailChanged = (text) => {
      return {
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        payload: text
      };
    };

    export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
      return {
        type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
        payload: text
      };
    };

    export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);

            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
              .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
              .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
          });
      };
    };

    const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
    };

    const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
      });
    dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'EmployeeCreate' }));
    };
```

AuthReducer.js

```
import {
    EMAIL_CHANGED,
    PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
    LOGIN_USER
  } from '../actions/types';

  const INITIAL_STATE = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    user: null,
    error: '',
    loading: false
  };

  export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case EMAIL_CHANGED:
        return { ...state, email: action.payload };
      case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
        return { ...state, password: action.payload };
      case LOGIN_USER:
        return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
      case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload };
      case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
        return { ...state, error: 'Authentication Failed.', password: '', loading: false };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dispatch` method of Redux. You should be using the `dispatch` method of React-navigation instead. You can do one of these:

1) Do `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'EmployeeCreate' }))`

2) Or integrate `React-navigation` with `Redux` ( recommended for your case especially ) and use Redux's default `dispatch`. I have created a barebones repo just for **[`react-navigation` + `Redux`](https://github.com/shubhnik/redux-react-navigation)**

Comment: thanks!! first option is not working for me.i'll try the second one

Answer (score 0):

React navigation with Redux flow is changed little bit in newer versions of React Navigation.

You can checkout the best way to do it from `3.x` in their documentation itself.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html